# Why can not I insert in the base text in Cyrillic on Backand servise?

Tags: string, insert, cyrillic, backand

When connecting through the MySQL client work insert and get value. But through the API inserted question marks.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the encoding. Post some of your code so we can try to find the problem.

Comment: I try add values on site. I have not used my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed the doc's then you can see the Cyrillic letters in the db.

I think you missed the last step which is to edit the connection details

1. Go to Setting => Database
2. Click Get Password and save it to the clipboard
3. If you don't see the "Edit Connection" button then add "/edit" to
   the browser url
4. On the username text box add ;CharSet=utf8;
5. Paste the password from the clipboard
6. Click Save